# How to recover parent value while creating parent and child layers in a embedded forms setup?

Tags: qgis, features, values, forms

I read the documentation, examples and made many attempts, but I still can't make this work.

What I want is to get a value from a parent layer while editing a child layer, when both features are being created in a embedded forms setup. So far, I can't seem to make current_parent_value() and current_value() work in an embedded forms setup.

I'm using QGIS 3.28 (tried with previous versions too) on Windows 10.

Let's say I have two nested forms: Form1 and Form2. Form2 is nested inside Form1 through a Relation. The 'fid' from Form1 and 'rel_id' from Form2 are used with the Relation to link both forms. I'm trying to get the value of 'Total' field from Form1 in Form2.

To try and understand what works and when I did this Case/When with a Coalesce.

```
case
when "rel_id" is not null then coalesce(  
current_parent_value('Total'),  
attribute(get_feature('Form1','fid',current_value('rel_id')),current_value('Total')),  
attribute(get_feature('Form1','fid',"rel_id"),'Total'),  
11111  
)  
else 00000  
end
```

The workflow is quite simple:

1. Create a feature in Form1
2. From this layer, create a child feature in Form2

[image]

In the end, I want my "value" field from the child feature to get the "Total" value from the parent feature. To be clear, this is a dummy project to test the function for something more useful than this.

When I create the feature, I get the '11111' value, which tells me my condition is caught, but no element of the coalesce work.
[image]

Then, when I update the feature afterward (change the value to trigger the "apply default value on update"), I finally get the right value, which tells me that the regular attribute(get_feature()) works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

But I really can't find a way to get the right value when creating the feature. In the end, I have the good value, but this confuses my users because they see the wrong value when they are working with the form in the field...

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample project to test the equation: [Here](https://obvyamaska.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/OBVYamaska_Public/Eh-q8yEBNAZJnw90tlRK2TQBLTlUKDyZNBNigrtHVwnzJQ?e=gR2e2U)

Comment: Which new `feature` function do you mean? To test any answers to you r question, one first has to start to rebuild the exactly same project/data as you have it. From the description it is a bit difficult to understand and, anyway, cumbersome to create an exactly matching project. So to boost your chances to get an answer, I would advice to post a link to a sample project with dummy data so that one can see what you have.

Comment: Sorry, there is no `feature` function in QGIS expressions. You mean `get_feature()` function? But this is not new.... Anyway - without a sample project or some screenshots, to me the questions remains unclear, even with the additions you made. Don't know why you don't want to post additional information and let people here working to re-create the setting you already have instead of helping them to help you solve your problem...

Comment: Hi @Babel , calm down, I'm very happy you want to help! I didn't receive any notification after your first comment, that's why my edit yesterday did not bring you the information you needed.
I added a linked at the end of my question for you to download a simple project to test the equation. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong and that it can quickly be solved, but I can't seem to figure out what.
I also removed the comment about the new "feature" variable (not function, you're right), as I think it's not what I need.

Comment: This is what I was referring to, but I realized that it replaced $currentfeature, not current_value(). My bad
Feature variable
https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#recent-functions

Comment: By "form" you mean "layer", right? That's a bit confusing. WOuld it not be easier to use a table join? By the way: for `fid`, you set a default value of `rand(1,10000)` - you should not do that, Geopackage handles unique fid-values automatically and interfering just complicates things and adds to the confusion about what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Inspecting your project, the whole logic of your project still remains a mystery to me... Adding a new feature in form 2, I'm not able to edit the `rel_id` field. Shouoldn't this be the case? How can you link to form 1 otherwise when there are added new features? Please try to describe your very workflow and the need for relations. Wouldn't a table join, a virtual layer or virtual fiel be better suited for your task? Are you sure your question is not a XY problem? See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/930719

Comment: It's a simplified project simply to highlight my original question: I can't find a way to recover the value of the parent layer when creating a new feature in a embeded form/layer. I tried with current_parent_value(), which is supposed to be designed for that, and with a combination of attribure(get_feature(current_value())), to no avail. As you can see in my example up there, even the solution you suggested, which is tested in my example, doesn't give you the right result when you are creating the feature. It only work if you try to recover the value from an already existing feature.

Comment: Don't mind the UID generation. 
"rel_id" is not editable because it will be populated automatically by the Relation when you create the child feature. It's, basically, the foreign key field to make the link between the layers.
The goal is to create complex embedded forms based on multiple layers hosted on a postGIS distant database. Virtual layers and field create editing problems in that kind of workflow, as far as I tested them. And yes, Relations are not so far from a table join, but are better managed by QGIS. They allow for a more complex interaction.

Comment: @Babel, I edited my project and my question to highlight the workflow. It's a simple 2 step actions, I hope it is clear enough now! I also got rid of the fid confusion if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To get

- the value of the field `Total` from layer `Form1`
- to layer `form2`,
- where the `rel_id` of `form2` is identical to the `fid` from `Form1`,

use this expression:

```
attribute (get_feature('Form1','fid',"rel_id"),'Total')
```